# How to update value for a certain key in a list of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I am new to Javascript. I have an object that looks like below

```
let final_json = {"ab": [{"cd": "ee", "col_val": {}},{"ef": "uu", "col_val": {"gg": "hh"}}]}
```

Now I want to update the `col_val` key's value with a defined value of my own. But I also need to ensure that the key `cd` exists in the given object.

This is what I do

```
if(final_json["ab"]) {    
    Object.entries(final_json["ab"]).forEach(([key, val]) => {
        if(final_json["ab"][key].hasOwnProperty("cd")) {
            // update the col_val value with {"rr": "ff"}
        }
    })
}
```

I am just not able to figure out how do I do that. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I use `.forEach` and just check for the `cd` property then update `col_val`.

```js
let final_json = {"ab": [{"cd": "ee", "col_val": {}},{"ef": "uu", "col_val": {"gg": "hh"}}]}
final_json.ab.forEach(o => {
  if (o.cd) o.col_val = {testKey: "testValue"}
})
console.log(final_json)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use map and check for cd using `hasOwnProperty()` function. `hasOwnProperty()` tells if a specific property is present in the object or not. [Refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```js
let final_json = {
  "ab": [{
    "cd": "ee",
    "col_val": {}
  }, {
    "ef": "uu",
    "col_val": {
      "gg": "hh"
    }
  }]
};
final_json.ab.map(e => {
  if (e.hasOwnProperty('cd'))
      e.col_val = 'my value'
    return e;
})
console.log(final_json)
```

Comment: why `map` if the returned array is void?

Answer (score 0):

You could find the wanted object and update the property, if found.

```js
let object = { ab: [{ cd: "ee", col_val: {} }, { ef: "uu", col_val: { gg: "hh" } }] },
    target = (object["ab"] || []).find(o => 'cd' in o);

if (target) {
    target.col_val = { rr: "ff" };
}

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```